# IEnumerable<string> gives result with values ["1","1"], it should give ["1","2"]

Tags: c#

I have below 2 classes which are inter-linked with each other,

```
 public class Class1
{
    public List<Class2> ClassTwo { get; set; }
}
public class Class2
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Class3> ClassThree { get; set; }
}
public class Class3
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

Then we have data for above classes like below,

```
Class1 collectionRequest = new Class1()
        {
            ClassTwo = new List<Class2>
        {
            new Class2 { Name = "1", ClassThree = new List<Class3> { new Class3 { Name = "A", Data = "X" } } },
            new Class2 { Name = "2", ClassThree = new List<Class3> { new Class3 { Name = "A", Data = "X" } } },
            new Class2 { Name = "3", ClassThree = new List<Class3> { new Class3 { Name = "B", Data = "Y" } } }
        }
        };
```

Now, I am running below LINQ,

```
var config = collectionRequest.ClassTwo
  .SelectMany(cp => cp.ClassThree)
  .GroupBy(cfg => cfg.Name)
  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, 
                g => g
                  .ToLookup(cfg => cfg.Data, 
                            cfg => collectionRequest.ClassTwo
                              .FirstOrDefault().Name));
```

When I am executing below, it's give me IEnumerable with values ["1","1"], but I would like to return IEnumerable with values ["1","2"].

**What changes required in LINQ?**

```
var data = config["A"]["X"]; // gives IEnumerable<string> with values ["1","1"]
```

Comment: The 'value' in your lookup is always `collectionRequest.ClassTwo.FirstOrDefault().Name`. Which is `1`. So it's doing what you've told it. What are you actually trying to do? The LINQ is rather hard to follow.

Comment: Ye, the main problem in computer science is that computer doesn't do what you want, but what you told it to do.

Comment: what about modifiing this: cfg => collectionRequest.ClassTwo.FirstOrDefault().Name

Comment: this line "cfg => collectionRequest.ClassTwo.FirstOrDefault().Name" is just I am checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your 'value' for the lookup is defined as this:

```
cfg => collectionRequest.ClassTwo.FirstOrDefault().Name
```

This ignores the parameter and always returns the name of first `Class2` instance - which is `1`.

The next issue is that you don't have any reference to the actual `Class2` instance the the `Class3` came from. You need to keep hold of that. You can do this using LINQ query syntax:

```
var c2c3ByC3Name =
    from c2 in collectionRequest.ClassTwo
    from c3 in c2.ClassThree
    group new {c2, c3} by c3.Name;
```

And you can, of course, do the same in method syntax:

```
var c2c3ByC3Name = collectionRequest.ClassTwo
    .SelectMany(x => x.ClassThree, (c2, c3) => new {c2, c3})
    .GroupBy(x => x.c3.Name);
```

You can then create your lookup similarly to before:

```
var config = c2c3ByC3Name
    .ToDictionary(
        grp => grp.Key,
        grp => grp.ToLookup(x => x.c3.Data, x => x.c2.Name));
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LJPlsp) for a working demo.